# Accessibility of forms in WinForms: TitleBar vs Application vs Default

Tags: .net, winforms, accessibility, screen-readers, jaws-screen-reader

I need my WinForms app to be accessible. I didn't alter the default `AccessibleRole` property of any control, hence they are set as `Default`. JAWS identifies the controls perfectly, but not the form itself. For example, JAWS announces the text of a button/the selected item of a listbox etc, But JAWS doesn't read the title from the title bar of the form.

So `Default` is out of option. I am just wondering why form alone is not read.

So I tried setting `AccessibleRole` property of the form to various others, and the only two choices that helped were `TitleBar` and `Application`. I did not find any difference between them as JAWS read the title bar the same. Which `AccessibleRole` should I ideally choose for a form? What are the differences between `TitleBar` and `Application`?

I am using .NET 4.0 and tested with JAWS 10 to 13, and makes no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JAWS has several *modes*, one of which is called forms mode. Essentially JAWS ignores everything except form elements.

> But JAWS doesn't read the title from the title bar of the form.

Try pressing <kbd>insert</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>.

> Which AccessibleRole should I ideally choose for a form?

For this question you should use `TitleBar`.

> What are the differences between TitleBar and Application?

The `TitleBar` role is to identify the title bar of the current window. The `Application` role is to indentify the whole application or the main window of an application. I am not a .net developer, so I cannot tell you if `TitleBar` is a child of `Application`.

Comment: Forms mode is only for HTML forms, which win forms are not.

Comment: Then what mode does it go into?

Comment: There is no special mode for normal windows applications.